# Issue with Tippy.js content

Tags: javascript, tippyjs

I took this example straight from [tippy.js documentation](https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/):

```
<button id="myButton">My Button</button>

tippy('#myButton', {
    content: "I'm a Tippy tooltip!",
});
```

I can't seem to make the `content` option work; but if I put a title attribute in the button element, the tippy tooltip appears!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`title` attribute on button is the default behaviour of the HTML button element.

Did you include the script? I tried below way(as mentioned in the docs) and it worked without any issues.

```
<button id="myButton">My button</button>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@popperjs/core@2"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tippy.js@6"></script>
<script>
   // With the above scripts loaded, you can call `tippy()` with a CSS
   // selector and a `content` prop:
   tippy('#myButton', {
     content: 'My tooltip!',
   });
</script>
```

[Demo](https://codepen.io/Amarnath510/pen/mdmPMXW)

Comment: I am working on a project which already had tippy.js and popper.js included but it turns out the scripts were not the correct version to make `content` work. I included the versions in your example and now it works fine!